# How to use a tidyverse-compatible code-formatting package in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, tidyverse, code-formatting

Jupyter notebook extensions contain a code-prettify extension that can be used to format the code, however for R code it uses the formatR package, which does not support the `%>%` pipe operator. How can I format my code in compliance with the tidyverse style guide in Jupyter Notebooks?

Answer (score 1):

Use the styler package instead of formatR. Install [Jupyter Notebook extensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) and add the following to `code_prettify` library call JSON in the configuration page:

```
{
  "r": {
    "library": "library(styler)\nlibrary(jsonlite)\n",
    "prefix": "cat(toJSON(paste(style_text(text=",
    "postfix": "), collapse='\n')))"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Jupyterlab Code Formatter](https://jupyterlab-code-formatter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#r-code-formatters) supports {styler} (which can handle `%>%`) for formatting in addition to {formatR}. There is also a corresponding issue in the {styler} repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/r-lib/styler/issues/807).